# How can I access all elements within a NodeList?

Tags: javascript, dom

With pure JavaScript, I've used this line to return a NodeList of multiple elements:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('icon-wrapper');
```

I can then use any of these lines to target a specific index from that NodeList:

```
elements[0];
elements[1];
elements[2];
```

But when I try to include multiple objects from the NodeList or loop through them, only one node, the last one requested, is returned.

I'm trying to apply `.appendChild` to all nodes with the class of `icon-wrapper`

Here is the code:

```js
var square = document.createElement('div');
square.style.width = "32px";
square.style.height = "32px";
square.style.zIndex = "-1";
square.style.position = "absolute";
square.style.backgroundColor = "red";
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('icon-wrapper');
var requiredElement = elements[0, 1, 2];
requiredElement.appendChild(square);
```

```css
body {
  background: lightyellow;
}
.icon-wrapper {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: green;
  float: left;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="icon-wrapper">
  <svg></svg>
</div>
<div class="icon-wrapper">
  <svg></svg>
</div>
<div class="icon-wrapper">
  <svg></svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Place the code within your question, not on a remote site.

Comment: `elements[0,1,2];` this does NOT select indeces 0, 1, and 2, it only selects index 2 because you are using the comma operator

Comment: There is no loop, nor do you use the code you've posted, in the fiddle? You're doing `elements[0,1,2]` and are expecting to somehow access multiple indices at once ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to achieve something like this? Check out :

```
https://jsfiddle.net/cd2gbuc9/3/
```

i.e:

```
1) Get the required elements.
   For each of them in a loop:
     1) Create a square
     2) Append the square to the element
```

Comment: But why would I do this, instead of just specifying the squares to start with in the HTML?

Comment: I thought the squares were not in the HTML to start with, that's why the code did document.createElement

Answer (score 0):

**Your logic is in error** in two ways:

1. The statement `elements[0,1,2]` is equivalent to `elements[2]`; it's only returning the last element, not all of them.
2. You're trying to add the same ONE square to multiple elements.  Even without error number 1, it would end up on the last element anyway, because there is only one square to go around.  If you want one square on *every* element in the NodeList, you need to *create one square for every element* in the NodeList, and then loop through it, appending a square on each iteration.  For example:

Convert the [NodeList to an Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList):

```
var node_list_array = Array.prototype.slice.call(div_list);
```

and append a *different* square to each element:

```
node_list_array.forEach(function(elem, index){ 
  elem.appendChild (squares[index]); 
});
```

Comment: OK, and then what do I do next?

Answer (score 0):

```
var requiredElement = elements[0,1,2];
```

This won't do what you think it does, whatever that is. It is equivalent to `var requiredElement = elements[2];`.

You need to get out of your jQuery mindset. You could start by not referring to "pure JavaScript"; all JavaScript is pure. DOM elements are not jQuery-like magical groups of things that you can simultaneously apply classes to, or append all of to something or append something to all of, or whatever. You will have to LOOP over a list resulting from something like `getElementsByClassName` and do whatever you want element-by-element.

In general, the use of `getElementsByClassName` itself is a code smell. Do not use classes as way to identify elements that you will then manipulate and insert and delete. Classes are a CSS construct, whose main purpose in life is to associate elements with CSS rules whose selectors specify those classes.

For example, instead of creating a `div` in code with laboriously assigned individual styles, and then trying to insert it here and there with code (hint: you can only include it in one place; if you insert it somewhere else it will MOVE there and be removed from where it was before), just add it to your HTML, with a class which brings in all those styles.

Answer (score 0):

There can be very different ways to achieve this. Easy ways create 3 different variable for square to be added. and then append them each using a for loop to each element.

Answer (score 0):

when you use getElementsByClassName result is "NodeList". the NodeList is a array of "node" and node can be "element" or "attribute" or "comment" and or "text".
you most check noteType in loop and only add elemnt to node type element that nodeType is 1.

```
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
{
    if(elements[i].nodeType === 1){
       elements[i].appendChild(square);
    }
}
```

for more information see this reference:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_nodetype.asp

Comment: This will not work, because there is a single square, and each time you append it, it will be removed from where it was before. Also, I have no idea why you are linking to a page from a disreputable site about the irrelevant `nodeType` property.

Answer (score 0):

First, [Document.getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName). This is something to be aware of if you are removing/adding elements during a loop, as it is a `live HTMLCollection`.

`var requiredElement = elements[0,1,2];` is not a way to access indexed items from an array like object, I don't know where you got that idea.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

So you need to iterate array like objects, by using iteration methods.

You need to create a new red box for each `appendChild`, otherwise you will just move the box from one place to another.

An example written in ES6.

```js
function createARedSquare() {
  const square = document.createElement('div');
  // use CSS for a class when possibe
  square.className = 'redSquare';
  return square;
}

//const slice = Function.prototype.call.bind(Array.prototype.slice);

// Gets a 'live' HTMLCollection and converts to an Array, a fixed node content
function getElementsByClassName(className) {
  // You could use Array#slice here instead of Array.from if < ES6
  return Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName(className));
}

function addRedSquareToEachIconWrapper() {
  getElementsByClassName('icon-wrapper')
    .forEach(iconWrapper => iconWrapper.appendChild(createARedSquare()));
}

addRedSquareToEachIconWrapper();
```

```css
body {
  background: lightyellow;
}
.icon-wrapper {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: green;
  float: left;
  margin: 2px;
}
.redSquare {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  background: red;
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="icon-wrapper">
  <svg></svg>
</div>
<div class="icon-wrapper">
  <svg></svg>
</div>
<div class="icon-wrapper">
  <svg></svg>
</div>
```